# Как сначала вывести первое значение переменной, а потом второй?

Tags: python, переменные

К примеру:

```
name = 'Josh', 'Ella'
print(вывести первое значение name)
print(вывести второе значение name)
```

как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вероятно так:

```
name = 'Josh', 'Ella'
print(name[0])
print(name[1])
```